# How to install mypeb in 64 bit server?

Tags: php, erlang

How to install PHP Erlang bridge in 64 bit server?

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/mypeb/issues/detail?id=4? You need to give us _much more_ information. What did you try, what problems arose …

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See http://code.google.com/p/mypeb/issues/detail?id=4